# Javascript add text to the head of document

Tags: javascript, atom-editor

I am writing a simple Atom.io package and would like to add a generic string to the head of the document using JavaScript :

```
var editor = atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor();
    if (editor) {
      console.log("Package Active");
      var selection = editor.getSelectedText();
      editor.insertText("Sample Text" + selection);
    }
  }
```

I can not understand why the text is being inserted at the position of the cursor and not at the head of the document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reposition the cursor to the head of the page using:

```
  editor.selectToTop();
```

Then add the desired text using:

```
  editor.insertText("Sample Text");
```

Comment: Works perfectly - Thanks for your help